# Ubuntu Tweak doesn't seem to work for me in Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-tweak

I've had Ubuntu Tweak installed for months now. However, there seems to be a list of things that don't seem to work when I change them in Ubuntu Tweak. No matter what I do, Ubuntu Tweak will not make the changes that I select.

- Tweaks -> Sound: does not work
- Tweaks -> Theme: no matter what theme I choose for any of the settings it does not change it in my system
- Tweaks -> Login Settings: does not change anything. doesn't even show the current cursor them that I am using

As I am writting this and going through Ubuntu Tweak, all of a sudden my panels and Cairo-Dock just disappear. Alt-Tab doesn't even work either and won't let me switch between applications.

Comment: It is Ubuntu, not Xubuntu Tweak, why do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Its because xubuntu uses a different ui. Whilst ubuntu uses unity, xubuntu uses xfce. Try this for changing the theme http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php?content=149647

Comment: Please include the gist of the solution here.

Comment: Ok I now have Xfce Theme Manager. Nifty little tool.